# How to solve webclient.downloadfile error 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, webclient

This line of code isn't working.

```
client.DownloadFile("http://www.tradecardsonline.com/img/cards/duel-masters/932/42.jpg", @"d:\a.jpg");
```

I know this question has been asked a lot but the other solutions aren't working for me.

Comment: That means, you don't have permission to download the file. Check and verify the same.

Comment: The link is working fine in Opera but error in Firefox for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser to access the link first.

You get 403 too. Your code is fine, but not the link.

Comment: The link is working fine in Opera but error in Firefox for some reason.